# ng-model : Doesn't work if input is already checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my checkbox...

I have several checkbox and when I activate or when I deactivate a checkbox, I add or I delete things thanks to functions. At this level there, everything is good. Except that if I leave a checkbox checked and if I reload my page, my function will leave this checked input.
But at this moment, when I try of unchecked the input which stayed checked, my function is not called and when I checked of new, my function of addition is called.

I think that my problem comes from my ng-model which does not include that my input is checked by default ...

What's to be done? 
Here is my HTML :

```html
<label class="toggle" ng-model="infoTeamCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Status" ng-checked="verifChecked(match.data.fixtures[$index].homeTeamName, match.data.fixtures[$index].awayTeamName)">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div ng-if="Status == true" ng-init="addIdMatch(match.data.fixtures[$index].homeTeamName, match.data.fixtures[$index].result.goalsHomeTeam, match.data.fixtures[$index].result.goalsAwayTeam, match.data.fixtures[$index].awayTeamName)"></div>
    <div ng-if="Status == false" ng-init="deleteIdMatch(match.data.fixtures[$index].homeTeamName, match.data.fixtures[$index].awayTeamName)"></div>
</label>
```

Here is my function which verifies if I owe checked the input or not :

```js
$scope.verifChecked = function(infoMatchHomeTeam, infoMatchAwayTeam) {
    if (localStorage.length >= 1)
    {
      $indiceIncrementation = 1;
      $trouve = false;
      while ($indiceIncrementation <= localStorage.length && $trouve == false)
      {
        var tabChaine = [];
        tabChaine[$indiceIncrementation] = localStorage[$indiceIncrementation].split("*");
        // On vérifie si l'input est dans le localStorage
        if (tabChaine[$indiceIncrementation][0] == infoMatchHomeTeam && tabChaine[$indiceIncrementation][3] == infoMatchAwayTeam)
        {
          $trouve = true;
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          $indiceIncrementation++
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I specify that I have several input of shown and who are shown according to a loop

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't use `ng-checked` and `ng-model` on same element (see docs). Also shouldn't be using `ng-init` for what you are doing either. Don't put controller business logic in the view

Comment: Sorry for my late. Then how to make be able to recover the status of an input already checked?

Comment: by using ng-model. It binds 2 ways

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I really don't understand...
I use Angular since 2 weeks thus I'm little bad but I want to learn this.
Can you show me on my code please ? :/

Comment: Study some tutorials. this isn't a tutorial service

Comment: If I ask for help it is because I have already looked and if I did not how find to solve this problem. I was confronted with many problems on what I want to make but I managed to solve them by reading doc or tutorials. But there I does not really understand how I can make and I do not really find. That's all...